# GData Java client library availability after April 20, 2015

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-admin-sdk, google-email-settings-api

Will the **GData Java client library v1.47.1** still be supported after the April 20, 2015 deprecation?

Comment: It's not longer actively supported, but some APIs may still work, it depends on which API. Refer to the readme on their [github repo](https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client).

Comment: The APIs concerned are Google Contacts API and Email Settings API

Answer (score 0):

Google Contacts API will be shut down on May 5, 2015

> Important: OAuth 1.0 has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012 and will stop being supported on May 5, 2015. It will continue to work until the shutdown date as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0. The Google Contacts API allows client applications to view and update a user's contacts. Contacts are stored in the user's Google Account; most Google services have access to the contact list.

[source](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)